# screen "xxx.xxx.x.xx" shape changed

Tags: synergy

I'm trying to setup synergy with Windows 7 (server, which is 192.168.1.51) and OpenSuse (client, which is 192.168.1.50). I've even tried a complete uninstall and reinstallation, but get the same error and can't connect. Here is my log:

```
Synergy 1.3.8 Server on Microsoft Windows 7 x64
This is an experimental x64 build of Synergy. Use it at your own risk.
started server
screen "192.168.1.51" shape changed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a few other complete re-installs and finally got it working

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else with this problem:

I didn't have this issue connecting my Win7 machine to my iMac, but when I upgraded my Win7 machine to Win10, I had to open up a port in the firewall for TCP port 24800.

1. Open Firewall Settings
2. In Inbound Rules, click "new Rule..."
3. Port -> TCP, "Specific local ports:" 24800, "Allow the Connection", Apply on Domain+Private, then Name & describe it (e.g. "Synergy, opens up port for Synergy)